# Question on $L^2(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ in variable $x$. Is it true that if $f \in L^2(\mu)$ i.e. $||f||_2 < \infty$, then $$||f(x-i)||_2 < \infty?$$ Note that $i= \sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: What space are you working in?  $\mathbb{R}$?  Or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I am working in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It's trivially true.  If $f$ is a polynomial, then $||f||_2 < \infty$ implies $f =0$.

Comment: What is your measurable space $X$ here? I suppose that $f$ is a polynomial in $\Bbb{C}$ and therefore $X=\Bbb{C}$. Also, when you put $\|f(x-i)\|_2$ do you mean $\|g\|_2$ where $g: X \to \Bbb{C}$ is given by $g(x)=f(x-i)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: And one more thing, is $\mu$ the Lebesgue/Area measure in $\Bbb{C}$? If so, I think that the solution is in @D_S comment. Otherwise, if $\mu$ is an arbitrary measure, I am not sure that we can assure that any polynomial in $L^2$  is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},\ f(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+...+a_{0},\ a_{n}\not=0$.

If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure: since $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^{n}}=a_{n}$, for $x$ large we have $\left |\frac{f(x)}{x^{n}}-a_{n}\right |<\frac{|a_{n}|}{2}$. So, by triangle's inequality $|f(x)|>\frac{|a_{n}|}{2}|x|^{n}$. So, $\int_{\mathbb{C}}|f|^2d\mu\geq\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{4}\int_{\mathbb{C}}|x|^{2n}d\mu=\infty$

If $\mu$ is the Dirac measure: $\int_{\mathbb{C}}|f|^{2}d\mu=|f(0)|^2<\infty$